# Rails: Checking if a user is signed in from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications

This is my first rails project. I have a web app with both a 'subscriber' and 'user' controller and module.
(subscribers only gave their email, users are signed in)

I'm trying to get users access to the list of subscribers, by creating an 'index' method in the subscriber controller, accessible only to users who are signed in.

I'm trying to do it using this

```
class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index]
def index
@subscribers = Subscriber.all
end
```

Where signed_in_user is defined as follows:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def signed_in_user
    unless signed_in?
      store_location
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
    end
end
```

and signed_in? is in the sessions helper:

module SessionsHelper
    def sign_in(user)
      cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
      self.current_user = user
    end

```
def current_user=(user)
  @current_user = user
end

def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end

def signed_in?
  !current_user.nil?
end
```

But it doesn't work as I don't have access to signed_in_user from the subscribers controller.
What would be the 'right' way to go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: As a comment on your direction, rather than have two models (and thus tables), why not define a scope in the User model: `scope :subscribers, where(:password => nil)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your UsersController include SessionsHelper, so that the function is accessible.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
include SessionsHelper
.......
end
```

Functions like signed_in? which are generally needed in many controllers, better to include helper in the application controller itself.